# Does tkinter have a table widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning Python, and I would like to use it to create a simple GUI application, and since `Tkinter` is already built-in (and very simple to use) I would like to use it to build my application.

I would like to make an app that will display a table that contains some data that I've loaded from my database.

I've searched for `table` but have not been able to find any examples and / or documentation regarding a `Tkinter table` component.

Does `Tkinter` have a built in `table` component? If not, what could I / should I use instead?

Comment: https://github.com/clarenceangel/tkinterstuff easy stuff perfect for beginners does exactly what you want.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4qLI9lmkqw  This is  imo the best table you can make with tkinter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't have a built-in table widget. The closest you can use is a `Listbox` or a `Treeview` of the tkinter's sub package [`ttk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html).

However, you can use [tktable](https://github.com/dossan/tktable), which is a wrapper around the `Tcl/Tk` [`TkTable`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1877) widget, written by [Guilherme Polo](https://github.com/gpolo). **Note**: to use this wrapper library you need first to have installed the original Tk's `TkTable` library, otherwise you will get an "import error".

Comment: Can't believe such a basic GUI display element such as a table is not included. C'mon tkinter...

Answer (score 51):

You can use Tkinter's grid.

To create a simple excel-like table:

```
try:
    from tkinter import * 
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

height = 5
width = 5
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)

mainloop()
```

You can grab the data by accessing the children of the grid and getting the values from there.

Comment: I think you forgot to add a `b.pack()`.

Comment: No, you should never mix grid and pack.

Comment: if I create a table like this how will I reference the fields after creation? If I got it right you are saying I can reference stuff with the grid coordinates?

Comment: @Steven: What does the "b" stand for? Is this a conventional name for `Entry`?

Answer (score 21):

If the table is read-only and you're using a sufficiently modern version of Tkinter you can use the [ttk.Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget.

You can also pretty easily create a grid of `Entry` or `Label` widgets. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049650/7432

Comment: great example [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/350266/creating-table-in-python)

Answer (score 17):

I am the author of a tkinter table widget written in pure python named `tksheet`. It only works for Python 3.6.3+.

It works using tkinter canvases and only redraws the visible portion of the table so it runs pretty smoothly even with hundreds of millions of cells

Among many other features you can also change any colors easily and highlight cells background and foreground

You can find the repository here: https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet

[image: tksheet basic example]

Comment: (I know this is irrelevant to this particular post but oh well) I've just started using your widget and it's amazing, however one thing I can't get to work is centering the actual sheet. I have the align = 'center', but having trouble centering the table within a frame using pack

Comment: @Sean2148 Actually, a correction to my first answer - You can center a widget in the y and x axis but not with `pack` only with `.grid()`

Comment: Do you think you could add a texteditor example to your docs?

Comment: Are there videos demonstrating interactions with `tksheet`, for example selecting several non-consecutive rows with Ctrl+click, then dragging&dropping them so that the order of rows changes, etc.?

Answer (score 15):

You could use [tkintertable](http://code.google.com/p/tkintertable/). See [the wiki](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable/wiki/Usage) how to start using it.

Comment: This now redirects to https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable where it states it's **for Python 2 only**

Comment: Freewind: Even though `tkintertable` is written for Python 2, it appears to be pure Python—so, since it's open source, updating it to work in Python 3 might not be too difficult.

Comment: if your using pandas, this one might be a good option: https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable

Comment: I observe no issues with python 3 so the comment by @handle seems outdated now.

Comment: This library is now Python 3 compatible!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @steven response, you can do this to reference any table cell

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

height = 5
width = 5
cells = {}
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
        cells[(i,j)] = b

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

## Using prettytable Library

Hi everyone , we can use prettytable library in order to make great tables like that of sql in tkinter.

Firstly execute the following code in cmd to install prettytable library

```py
pip install prettytable
```

now here is a self explanatory code for making table:

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from tkinter import *

win=Tk()

t=Text(win)#Inside text widget we would put our table

x=PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]

x.add_row(["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])

t.insert(INSERT,x)#Inserting table in text widget
t.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

### Output of this code:

[image]

Put the following line of code after t.insert(INSERT,x) in order to make this table read-only

```py
t.config(state=DISABLED)
```

This method would make tables very easily. If you are curious to know more about prettytable , [click here](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/clarenceangel/tkinterstuff i made this but I am no pro. It does create a table though and return it as a frame that you can add to a frame or root.You feed it a csv with any number of rows and columns so long as the columns are even on each row of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the tksheet widget, it is just like excel files in tkinter.
in which you can make tables also.
if you use windows you can install it using,

```
pip install tksheet
```

and when importing in tkinter you can use,

```
from tksheet import Sheet

import tkinter as tk
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Jojojustin and @Steven - making the "table" responsive

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

row = 5
col = 5
cells = {}
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        root.columnconfigure(j,weight=20) # making the columns responsive 
        root.rowconfigure(i,weight=20) # making the rows responsive 
        b = Entry(root,text="")
        b.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=NSEW)
        cells[(i,j)] = b
root.mainloop()
```