# Creating a table look-a-like Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking to create something that resembles a table in Tkinter but it doesn't necessarily have to be one.

I would like to create headers 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Value' for example and beneath each one I wish to have several blank rows.

These rows I then wish to fill in later (therefore a Label) with values I have calculated or string values for names.

For 'Name2' I would actually like for the entire column to be a drop down menu. I have already created the code for one on it's own but am not sure how to incorporate it into this 'table'.

Is it for example possible to create a border around a Label widget so it looks like a 'table'?

Any pointers towards what would be possible in this situation would be very much appreciated. If you require any of my code to have a go at something, just ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What problem are you having? The simple solution is to lay out widgets using `grid`. You can put whatever type of widget you want in each cell. And yes, labels can have borders. Though, a simple way to do grid lines is to use a padding around each cell, so that the color of the frame will show through the gaps.

Do this in a frame. If you need to be able to scroll the table, put the frame inside a canvas and add scrollbars. There are examples all over the web for how to create a scrollable frame using a canvas.

Here's a really quick example that uses just labels, and doesn't scroll. I'll leave the exact implementation of what you need as an exercise for the reader.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        t = SimpleTable(self, 10,2)
        t.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        t.set(0,0,"Hello, world")

class SimpleTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=10, columns=2):
        # use black background so it "peeks through" to 
        # form grid lines
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black")
        self._widgets = []
        for row in range(rows):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(columns):
                label = tk.Label(self, text="%s/%s" % (row, column), 
                                 borderwidth=0, width=10)
                label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                current_row.append(label)
            self._widgets.append(current_row)

        for column in range(columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)


    def set(self, row, column, value):
        widget = self._widgets[row][column]
        widget.configure(text=value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: My only problem now is that I've never really used 'self' or '__init__' much and don't quite understand how to incorporate my other functions for menus etc. Would you be able to give me some advice (for extreme beginners!) please?

Comment: For example, I'm even a little confused as to how to assign a name to the Frame...but I have functions for opening and menus etc.

Comment: @user20: why do you think you need to assign a name to the frame? In the above example, `t` holds a reference to the frame, that's all you need to be able to use it.

Comment: What does `self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)` do? (I tried omitting this part of your example and see NO change) (Python 3.6)

Comment: @Siemkowski: it tells the grid geometry manager how to allocate extra space. If you omit the code, you will see a difference as soon as you manually resize the widget to make it bigger.

Answer (score 4):

A fairly simple object-less solution I found:

```
from Tkinter import *

rows = []
for i in range(5):
    cols = []
    for j in range(4):
        e = Entry(relief=RIDGE)
        e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
        e.insert(END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
        cols.append(e)
    rows.append(cols)

def onPress():
    for row in rows:
        for col in row:
            print col.get(),
        print

Button(text='Fetch', command=onPress).grid()
mainloop()
```

or

```
# simple 2d table

from Tkinter import *

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(4):
        l = Label(text='%d.%d' % (i, j), relief=RIDGE)
        l.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)

mainloop()
```

All available at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/

Answer (score 0):

How to create table from a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    1: {'Header1': 'Row1_Value1', 'Header2': 'Row1_Value2', 'Header3': 'Row1_Value3', },
    2: {'Header1': 'Row2_Value1', 'Header2': 'Row2_Value2', 'Header3': 'Row2_Value3', },

    }

# Create the header
for column, header in enumerate(my_dict[1]):
    Label(self, text=header).grid(row=0, column=0+column)

# Fill in the values
for row, element in enumerate(my_dict.values()):
    for column, (header, value) in enumerate(element.items()):
        Label(self, text=value).grid(row=1+row, column=0+column)
```