# Python 3 tkinter - create a simple table with scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tableview

I am very new to `tkinter`. I searched around for a bit and found the following post, which explains how to create a simple table widget: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049650/1829329

Now I'd like to add a scrollbar to it. I read that you have to give the widget, which will have the scrollbar the `set` method of the scrollbar and the scrollbar the `yview` method of the widget, to make them work together.

However, the linked implementation of a table doesn't have a `yview` method.

How can I add a working `scrollbar` to the linked implementation?

Comment: There are probably dozens of examples on this site  of adding a scrollbar to a frame by putting the frame in a canvas.

Comment: A Frame inside a canvas? Is that the usual way to go about adding scrollbars to object, which doesn't have the `yview`?

Comment: Yes, it is the normal way people do that. You could also add a frame to a text widget since it's scrollable and supports embedded widgets, but that's a bit less common.