# In python 3, how to draw a grid with data in it (like excel)

Tags: python

How to draw (I mean graphically, not just print on console) a grid with data in it, like excel does it ?
Just a matrix of strings displayed by row.
I found nothing in Matplotlib.

Comment: Yes, I spent 20 minutes to do so, and found nothing but plenty of matplotlib which does not answer the question: only scientific display which is not what I'm look for

Comment: you could make a GUI using something like PythonCard

Comment: it's very easy to do such a thing in GUI. try tkinter

Comment: You could use `openpyxl` to actually put it in an excel sheet...  Are you asking how to write an excel-like program in python?

Comment: No, I just want to display a bunch of rows in an grid (like an excel grid, or an html table)

Comment: parse if with `pyxlrd` and write it as HTML? sounds pretty straightforward.

Comment: Matplotlib has tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137396/matplotlib-table-only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11047803/7432

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create simple grid with some data you can use `Tkinter` like this

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Entry, mainloop, StringVar

root = Tk()

height = 5
width = 5
for i in range(height):  # Rows
    for j in range(width):  # Columns
        text_var = StringVar()
        # here we are setting cell text value
        text_var.set('%s%s' % (i, j)) 
        b = Entry(root, textvariable=text_var)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. I never did gui in python - and did not know about tkinter. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe there is some better way to draw the grid with Python, but this is the fastest solution that I was able to create.

Comment: This looks exactly like the answer I linked :-)

Comment: You don't need to use the `StringVar`, though it's harmless if you want to use it. It just adds one more object you have to manage. You should also give every row and column a weight and use the `sticky` attribute so that the widget behaves well when the window resizes.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a GUI toolkit that allows you to show a window with a data table that you can populate.
I first thought of [Qt](http://www.qt.io/)'s QListWidget that you could use via [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). But Python already comes with [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), so you could continue your research at https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming.

Comment: tKinter does not have a table widget, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget