# Creating a column from desktop text file and identifying it as positive, negative or neutral sentence in python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a (nx2) table in python gui, where n is my no.of sentences in a text file and my second column will consist of a scrollbar where I can manually assign (positive or negative or neutral) value to it.Currently, I am able to get the sentences from text file using the below code:-

```
root=Tk()

def openInstruktion():
    from subprocess import call
    call("notepad c:\\Users\\Desktop\\tweets.txt")

instruktionBtn = Button(root, text='tweets', command=openInstruktion)
instruktionBtn.grid(row=6, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Gui should be like this:-[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: As I am new to tkinter haven't tried much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does tkinter have a table widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget)

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a free code-writing service. You need to attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then as a _specific_ question when you get to the part of the problem that you are struggling with.

Comment: @BryanOakley Actually, I am stuck after getting the text file data and wanted to know about how can I create a column in front of that particular sentence that I am getting from the textfile?

Comment: @Shirohige what are you doing with this column you want to create?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I want to create 2 columns in 1st column I want to get the sentences from the text file and in the 2nd column, I want to manually select from the scrollbar whether the sentence is positive, negative or neutral. I have gone through the Tkinter tutorials still I didn't understand how to code it.

Comment: your use of the word column is confusing. You want to create 2 columns in the 1st column? That doesn't make any sense. Maybe you are trying to create 2 columns that are both left of the rest of the program?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I've uploaded an image of my table format. 1st column contains sentences from a text file. And 2nd column contains a scrollbar to assign sentiment for a particular sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

First of all, to read the tweets from your text file try using [.readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list):

```
# Get the list of tweets from a text file
with open("c:\\Users\\summert\\Desktop\\tweets.txt") as f:
    tweets = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
```

Then, a simple way to create your "table" is to align widgets using the [grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049650/4084269) method.

Finally, you can add a [scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/4084269) if the table gets too long:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
label_tweet = tk.Label(root, text="Tweet", width=28)
label_tweet.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20,0), pady=5)
label_sentiment = tk.Label(root, text="Sentiment", width=15)
label_sentiment.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,30), pady=5)

# Create a table container with a scrollbar using a canvas
table_container = tk.Frame(root)
table_container.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20)
canvas = tk.Canvas(table_container, highlightthickness=0)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(table_container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
vsb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")

# Put the tweets in a hand-made "table"
possibleSentiments = ["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"]
sentimentBoxes = []
for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    # Create an entry box for the tweet
    e = ttk.Entry(frame, width=35)
    e.insert(0, tweet)
    e.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    # Create a combobox for the associated sentiment
    c = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=possibleSentiments, width=12, state="readonly")
    c.set(possibleSentiments[1])
    c.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
    sentimentBoxes.append(c)

# Add a button to save the tweets and sentiments in a CSV file
def saveSentiments():
    sentiments = [c.get() for c in sentimentBoxes]
    print(sentiments)
    with open('tweetSentiments.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        for i in range(len(tweets)):
            csvfile.write('"{}","{}"\n'.format(tweets[i], sentiments[i]))

button = tk.Button(root, text="Save sentiments", command=saveSentiments)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

# Resize the canvas
root.update()
frame_width = frame.winfo_width()
canvas.config(width=frame_width, height=140)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

# Launch the app
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not able to access all row values.

Comment: You can use the `get()` method on the boxes to read their values (see my edited answer).

Comment: I am unable to view all rows as there is no scrollbar in the gui.

Comment: After 32 rows I am unable to scroll down.

Comment: I added the scrollbar implementation (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/4084269 for more info).

Comment: One final request how can I save both sentiment as well as tweet(table wise).

Comment: To save tweets and sentiments together, you can put them in a csv file (see my latest edit)

Comment: Thanks for your help.