# python 3.6, GUI, tkinter, a button to remove the row

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am using python 3, GUI, tkinter.
i use grid method (row and column) to create a table containing info, a button is placed in the end of each row. if someone press that button, the whole row will disappear/destroy and next row will replace it, which function should i use to achieve that?

Comment: Hi @Pandova, could you post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grid_forget()](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method) method will cause the grid geometry manager to stop managing a widget. So if you put your widgets for a row into a frame and grid that, you can grid_forget the frame to have all the widgets in the frame removed from display together. However, you might want to investigate the Ttk [treeview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview) which can display tabular information or the tktable package (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9348306/291641)).