# Display sqlite3 data in python

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface

I am trying to build little window viewer of my sqlite3 database but unfortunetly I cannot find a way. So far I have reached something like below, but instead displaying table it shows whole sets of dictionaries representing each row of sqlite3 table.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

main=Tk()
main.geometry('400x400')
main.title('Get data')

def show_data():
    with sqlite3.connect('Data.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
    obj = c.fetchall()
    Label(main,text = obj).pack()

but = Button(main, text = 'Show',font = ('',10),command=show_data)
but.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

[set of dictionaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCYhK.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what you got?

Comment: May be this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of cracked it this way

```
def show(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Data.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * From data")
        records = c.fetchall()
        print_records = ''
        for record in records:
            print_records += str(record[0])+"  "+"\n"+str(record[1])+"  "+str(record[2])+"  "+str(record[3])+"  "+str(record[4])+"  "+str(record[5])+"  "+str(record[6])+"  "+str(record[7])+"  "+str(record[8])+"  "+str(record[9])+"  "+str(record[10])+"  "+str(record[11])+"  "+str(record[12])+"  "+str(record[13])+"  "+str(record[14])+"  "+str(record[15])+"  "+str(record[16])+"  "+str(record[17])+"  "+str(record[18])+"  "+str(record[19])+"  "+str(record[20])+"  "+str(record[21])+"  "+str(record[22])+"  "+str(record[23])

        query_label = Label(self.main, text = print_records)
        query_label.grid(sticky = E, row=5, column=0, pady = 45, columnspan=23)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

But thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the fetched data in a pandas `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

def show_data():
    with sqlite3.connect('Data.db') as db:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM data", c)

    Label(main,text = df).pack()
```