# Python GUI with user input area similar to excel

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, input

I am attempting to create a GUI that allows for users to copy and paste data straight into the interface. There will be three columns and anywhere between 1 - 500 rows with the possibility of 3,000+ The raw text will come via email, word, PDF, or excel so I need the user input field to be similar to excel in that you can copy/paste more than 1 line at a time.

I have followed a couple YouTube guides on creating tables/grids with tkinter however I cannot figure out a way to allow text entry via copy/paste.

One of the only ways I found to make tables with tkinter since tktable isn't a part of it is the following example. This still does not allow for user input via copy/paste.

```
  
  
class Table: 
      
    def __init__(self,root): 
          
        # code for creating table 
        for i in range(total_rows): 
            for j in range(total_columns): 
                  
                self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='blue', 
                               font=('Arial',16,'bold')) 
                  
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
                self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j]) 
  
# take the data 
lst = [(1,'Raj','Mumbai',19), 
       (2,'Aaryan','Pune',18), 
       (3,'Vaishnavi','Mumbai',20), 
       (4,'Rachna','Mumbai',21), 
       (5,'Shubham','Delhi',21)] 
   
# find total number of rows and 
# columns in list 
total_rows = len(lst) 
total_columns = len(lst[0]) 
   
# create root window 
root = Tk() 
t = Table(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative to tkinter or point me in the direction of a guide for this type of user input?

Comment: This is very hard. Unless you can use a library it will take a lot of code. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9348306/11106801). If that didn't help, you can try binding to `Ctrl+v`/`Ctrl+x`/`Ctrl+c` and create the logic yourself.

Comment: Use `ttk.Treeview`?

Comment: @CoolCloud - I'm working through a YouTube guide for Treeview but wanted to ask the question; can I have a column for user input?

Comment: I dont think it is possible directly through treeview, though I suppose you can always take in user input with `Entry` and then use that to make the treeview columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why I couldn't get python to allow me to use tkinter and was able to do what I was trying to do, more or less.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT

HEIGHT = 970
WIDTH = 1500

root = tk.Tk()
root.title( 'Daves Generator')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='david.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame_one = tk.Frame(root, bg='#003d70',bd=5)
frame_one.place(relx=0.17, rely=.15, relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

customer_description = tk.Text(frame_one, state=NORMAL, width=125, wrap=WORD, height=500,font=("Courier", 8))
customer_description.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame_two = tk.Frame(root, bg='#003d70',bd=5)
frame_two.place(relx=0.5, rely=.15, relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

dave_description = tk.Text(frame_two, width=125, height=500,font=("Courier", 8))
dave_description.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame_three = tk.Frame(root, bg='#003d70',bd=5)
frame_three.place(relx=0.83, rely=.15, relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

sap_code = tk.Label(frame_three, width=125, height=500,font=("Courier", 8))
sap_code.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

header_frame_one = tk.Label(root, text="Customer Descriptions", font=("Courier", 14), fg='#003d70')
header_frame_one.place(relx=0.17, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

header_frame_two = tk.Label(root, text="PJ Descriptions", font=("Courier", 14), fg='#003d70')
header_frame_two.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

header_frame_three = tk.Label(root, text="SAP Code", font=("Courier", 14), fg='#003d70')
header_frame_three.place(relx=0.83, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

generate_button = tk.Button(root,text="Generate!", font=("Courier", 14), fg='white', bg='#003d70', command=lambda: get_customer_description())
generate_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.08, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')
```